# Right Function between SUMIFS or SUMIF function in Excel

Tags: excel

I have some alphanumeric data in column A on sheet A. Something like this:-

```
 abcd-1234
```

and so on and some value corresponding to every value in col B.

On another sheet i have 1234 means only the numeric part of this data on sheet B. Now i want to sum the data on col B on Sheet A with matching value in Sheet A. I have tried this so far:-

```
=SUMIFS(A!$A$1:$A$100,RIGHT(A!$B$2:$B$100,4),$A1)
```

But it is not working. Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation and your formula don't match. Let's assume column A has the alpha-numeric values and column B has the values you want to sum.

Try Sumproduct. Also when you extract the numbers from the text with the RIGHT() function, the result will still be text. If the value in A1 is a number, you need to coerce the extracted text into numbers.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A!$B$1:$B$100*((RIGHT(A!$A$2:$A$100,4)+0)=$A1))
```

Comment: My requirements have been changed a bit now. Is there any way that this formula works for the any last row irrespective of the end row not only for A1:A100. As the data can be changed on the source sheet.

Comment: Use an Excel Table (insert > Table) and instead of cell references use the table column names in structured referencing. `=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[ColumnB]*((RIGHT(Table1[ColumnA],4)+0)=$A1))`. Replace table name and column names according to your table.